# Java Web Start, JPG as the resource

Tags: java, image, resources, java-web-start

I would like to use a jpeg file as a default image in my JWS application. The application is allowed to work with the client system resources, the user may upload any image. The project is developed in NetBeans 8.1.

The following steps have already been done:

1] Inside the "build" folder, new folder "resources"  was created. The jpeg file "test.jpg" was uploaded.

2] Using NetBeans/Project Properties/Sources/Add folder the folder "resources" was added to the source package folders.

3] The class constructor of the class derived from JPanel downloads the data from resources

```
public class TestExample extends JPanel {

    public TestExample() {
            try
            {
                    URL resource = TestExample.class.getResource("/test.jpg");
                    String file_name = resource.getFile().toString();  //Error
                    img = ImageIO.read(new File(file_name));
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) 
            {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

In a local copy, the software works well. Uploading the signed jar, classes and resources to the destination location, the current window with security warning appears. After accepting and pushing OK the main form does not appear but the exception

```
Error: Unexpected exception java.lang.NullPointerException in line ...
```

which refers to the line

```
String file_name = resource.getFile().toString();
```

Probably, the resource has not been found.... In my opinion, the problem may be due to the lack of information about the resource in the jnlp file

```
<resources>
    <!-- Application Resources -->
    <j2se version="1.7+"
          href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="TestExample.jar"
        main="true" />

</resources>
<application-desc
     name="Test"
     main-class=
       "testexample.TestExample"
     width="800"
     height="600">
 </application-desc>
 <update check="background"/>
 <security>
     <all-permissions/>
 </security>
```

Another idea: the obtained URL may not be converted to String

```
 String file_name = resource.getFile().toString();
```

When the code inside the try block is disabled, the application works correctly. However, any JPEG file from the client PC may be uploaded, so the application works with the client data correctly. Inside the manifest file, the security is also set:

```
Permissions: all-permissions
```

May I ask for your help? Thanks...

Comment: `img = ImageIO.read(new File(file_name));` Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: BTW - Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).